# What variable is sent in every PayPal IPN?

Tags: paypal

I've been trying to base my IPN off `txn_type`, then `payment_status` but I've been getting exceptions since not every IPN has those. What variable can I base my IPN off of?

`txn_type` was not sent in refund IPNs.

Comment: Because I can see it my PayPal dashboard, and the `payment_status` says Refunded.

Comment: Refund IPN's do have a txn_id, which is the refund transaction ID, and then it also has a parent_txn_id, which is the original transaction ID that was refunded.  [Here's a sample](http://sandbox.angelleye.com/paypal/ipn/admin/raw-log-detail.php?id=13061).

Comment: If `txn_type` is null you should get it from the `txn_type` of the transaction given by `parent_txn_id`, which you should already have in your database. But that tells you what the *original* `txn_type` was. You may have to combine that with the `payment_status` field, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, txn_type isn't sent with every IPN type.  There isn't really any one field you can look at and always count on.  What you need to do is setup logic to check for different fields and their availability as well as their value.

So I would check for txn_type, and if it exists, go ahead process according to that type.  If it doesn't exist, though, then you can fall to other parameters to figure out what's going on and how to process it within your logic.

For example, if you take a look at [this sample refund IPN data](http://sandbox.angelleye.com/paypal/ipn/admin/raw-log-detail.php?id=13061), you'll see it includes a payment_status of "Refunded" as well as a reason_code of "refund".  So your logic can look for those values accordingly, and it would then know it's a refund.